# Chirp Audio QR Fails to receive audio signals on ipad after resuming from background

Tags: ios, swift, audio, avaudiosession, chirp

Chirp audio QR frame work is not receiving data after resuming from background (This issue is only happening on iPAD devices iOS11+)

If the app is in foreground then framework works without having any issues, but if app goes background and then resuming this happens.

Answer (score 0):

Joe from Chirp here. Are you stopping the SDK when moving to the background, and starting again in the foreground?

See our example project at https://github.com/chirp/chirp-ios-examples/blob/master/Swift/Messenger/ChirpMessenger/AppDelegate.swift for an example of this.

I have just tested this on an iPad running iOS 11.4.1 and data is still received when foregrounded.

Comment: I wrote all the application state based codes but still no luck, now chirp is stopping on background and starting on resume.  Also i observed that when i enable audio background mode in capabilities this seems to be working but i don't think that i can publish to appstore with those capabilities enabled.

Comment: Example project https://github.com/chirp/chirp-ios-examples/tree/master/Swift/Messenger is also not working after entering background (Receiving part is broken)

Comment: Can you check that the SDK version you are using is up to date? Current version is v3.5.2.

Comment: @joerobot yes I have check version 3.5.2 on 7th July 2019. Can you resolve this receiving part ? then please share knowledge with me.

Answer (score 0):

I you want the app to receive/record audio when it goes into the background state, then Background Audio must be set in the Capabilities plist.  Otherwise the OS will remove the microphone connection from your app's process (to allow the new foreground app to possibly use it).